# How should dates from distinct time zones should be properly handled?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm receiving dates in the format: `'MM/DD/YY HH:mm'`, I can know what timezone the date *comes from*. I'm trying to be aided by moment-timezone in order to convert them to standard Javascript UTC date according to that timezone.

This is an example of what I'm trying:

```
var startTime = '12/03/15 14:00'
var zoneOffset = moment(startTime, 'MM/DD/YY HH:mmZ').tz('America/Chicago').format().substring(19);
var tzAdjusted = moment(startTime + zoneOffset, 'MM/DD/YY HH:mmZ');
var date = tzAdjusted.toISOString();
```

Then, I tried to test my logic:

```
describe('Timezone conversions', function () {
    it('Should properly convert timezones despite of running environment', function (done) {

    var startTime = '12/03/15 14:00'
    var zoneOffset = moment(startTime, 'MM/DD/YY HH:mmZ').tz('America/Chicago').format().substring(19);
    var offset = moment(startTime + zoneOffset, 'MM/DD/YY HH:mmZ').format();
    offset.slice(-6).should.equal('-06:00');
    done();
    })
});
```

As I'm running this in México which is at *same* timezone offset as Chicago will run good, but if I set my timezone to UTC before running (`export TZ='UTC'`) what will fail.

What's proper and correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I try avoid this issue by saving all dates and times as Posix time stamps (the number of seconds elapsed since Jan 1, 1970, GMT). You can get the current time stamp really quickly like so:

```
var the_time_right_now = Date.now();
```

And that's it. There are all sorts of methods that come along with the Date object that will help you convert times from there based on timezone, etc.

Comment: I'm sorry but your answer doesn't _answer_ anything. From the problem scenario I introduce in my question, it remain the same with your apport.